# Creating a USB device driver for Linux

Tags: python, c, linux, usb, driver

My dad is interested in switching over to Linux, but there are a few things holding him back. The one item he can't live without is his Corex CardScan 700c. He uses it on a weekly basis, and has tens of thousands of contacts stored with it. The 700c is not supported under Linux, but is it possible to create a USB driver for the scanner? I know nothing about device drivers for Linux, but from my understanding I can have it run in two different places: kernel-space and userspace. Kernelspace requires C/Assembly, where as in userspace I might be able to get away with using Python (right?). Does anyone know anything about this topic, or know of any good guides/books relating to it? I would describe myself as a 'programming enthusiast' but am willing to learn. Thank you for your help and input.

Comment: This is a difficult task. See a related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24297/how-do-i-get-a-cardscan-60-ii-working-with-sane

Comment: I'm the last person to discourage a person from taking on a difficult task that has educational value; but I feel compelled to do so in this case. Using something like libusb might make it possible to do the job in userspace rather than the kernel, and remove some of the considerable learning burden of kernel programming. But the real problem here will be reverse-engineering the scanner's USB protocol, which will probably be undocumented. My experience is that this kind of thing is time-consuming and frustrating, and the results have really, really got to be worth it for it to be justifiable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the python way you may want to look at [libusb1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libusb1). Some [usage examples](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libusb1#usage) are described in the documentation of this python module. You will of course be exposed to a lot of device interaction but if you are "willing to learn" you can start of from here. Good luck with your coding/hacking!